# Get only date win windows phone development

Tags: c#

How do I get only date eg : 2011-03-04 in windows phone development environment in Visual studio for windows phone? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Date property of the DateTime type :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx

Comment: I want to get the date from a datepicker